# ng-pluralize, Add the bootstrap class

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angularjs-directive

In my code, based on the result, I am displaying the message using

```
<span ng-if="data.length >= 1" class="badge badge-success">{{data.length}}</span>
<span ng-if="data.length == 0" class="badge badge-error">{{data.length}}</span>
```

2 Doubts :

First:

```
 <ng-pluralize count="data.length" offset=2
        when="{'0'    : 'No driver. :-(',
        '1'  : ' driver !',
        '2'  : ' {{data[0].Driver.givenName}}, {{data[1].Driver.givenName}} driver !',
        'other': ' {{data[0].Driver.givenName}}, {{data[1].Driver.givenName}} and {} others.'}">
    </ng-pluralize>
```

Above code displays :

Found: 13 Sebastian, Fernando and 11 others.

[image]

I know that the first green oval is from `<span />` tag with class "badge badge-success",

What if I Want to color the other integer value (11) to

```
<span class="badge badge-warning">11</span>
```

I mean I should get the result like :

[image]

Second:

```
<!--span ng-class="{ 'badge badge-success' : data.length > 1, badge badge-error }"> {{data.length}}</span--> //Why this is not working ?
Anyways, This I have achieved by using `ng-if` by using 2 span tags, but just for my understanding what is wrong in this span tag conditioning.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I chose an Alternative solution, Used `ng-switch`

```
<div ng-switch="data.length">
                        <div ng-switch-when="0">No drivers. :-(</div>
                        <div ng-switch-when="1">1 driver!</div>
                        <div ng-switch-when="2">{{data[0].Driver.givenName}} and {{data[1].Driver.givenName}} driver !</div>
                        <div ng-switch-default>{{data[0].Driver.givenName}}, {{data[1].Driver.givenName}} and
                            <span class="badge badge-info">{{data.length - 2}}</span> other !</div>
                    </div>,
```

Now it works fines, as I was except for